# OpenCV python webcam won’t show an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

When I tried to use OpenCV with my webcam it only shows this image

[image: OpenCV Result]

How can I fix this?

```
import cv2
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError(“Cannot read webcam”)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read(0)
    cv2.imshow(‘frame’,frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(‘q’):
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages ?

Comment: you use wrong quotation marks `“ ”` and `‘ ’` - it should be `" "` and `' '`

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but where the wifi symbol and that sort of target come from?

Comment: @ndrplz that’s what I get instead of seeing my webcam feed

Comment: @furas no how would I do that?

Comment: if I rember `Win+R` should open window where you can put `cmd.exe` to run it and then you can run scripe using `python.exe your_script.py`. But if you don't know how to use `cmd.exe` then you may have other problem like "how to go to folder with script", "how to use full path to run python"